# Probability that a ball drawn from a box, after drawing some balls, is white

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

Suppose we have a box of $n$ balls, from which, $n_1$ balls are white. we draw $k$ balls ($k<n$) from the box and we put them aside "**without seeing them**". What is the probability that the next ball drawn from the box is white?

I know that the answer is the same for a problem in which we draw only one ball. But why is that? Is there a mathematical proof for this?

Comment: The punchline is that each of the $n$ balls will be equally likely to have appeared as the next ball drawn.  The result follows.